# Filter by string format in R

Tags: r, string, filter, tidyverse

I have an ID column that should always be formatted `ABCDE123` - Five letters and three numbers, no gap no symbols.

I know for sure there are a number of rows that don't correctly follow this format. Is it possible to filter by the string format in R, so that I can identify those rows and review them?

Tidyverse is preferred, but any solution would be helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If these are 5 upper case letters followed by 3 digits, specify regex to match 5 upper case letters `[A-Z]{5}` from the start (`^`) of the string followed by 3 digits (`[0-9]{3}`) at the end (`$`) of the string in `str_detect` to return a logical vector which is used in `filter`ing the rows of the data

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
    filter(str_detect(ID, '^[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{3}$'))
```

---

If these rows should be removed, specify `negate = TRUE` in `str_detect`

```
df1 %>%
    filter(str_detect(ID, '^[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{3}$', negate = TRUE))
```

Or as @BenBolker mentioned in the comments `[[:upper:]]{5}` would be more generic compared to `[A-Z]{5}`

Comment: PS hope the frequent comments don't bug you too much. I usually start answering but then you answer faster!

Comment: @BenBolker Not at all. I was confused which subset the OP wanted from the description.  Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: df1 %>% filter(str_detect(ID, '^[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{3}$') == FALSE) allowed me to review incorrect entries before I remove them. [[:upper:]] also worked well.